# A trivial typo in the answer of a question.

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

The question is given in the following picture:

[image]

I am speaking about 2(b), the direction ($\Leftarrow$), the answer is given in the following picture:

[image]

I think that the 2 functions g & h should be named k & t respectively, am I right?

Also the line before last, which says:"But as Imf $\neq$ B, k $\neq$ t, contrary to the assumption that k = t", I see that k $\neq$ t from their definitions not because Imf $\neq$ B, am I right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds to me like you have the right idea about the first thing but not the second.

The answer assumes a general hypothesis about any $k$ and $t$. Then it introduces some particular maps $g$ and $h$, and applies the general hypothesis to them. But starting from the displayed equation, it uses $k$ and $t$ to refer to them. Oops! I think it would be fine to call the maps $g$ and $h$, but then they should be consistently referred to by those names. Or else they could be called $k$ and $t$. (But as a stylistic matter, that does introduce a slight risk of confusing the reader between "general" $k$ and $t$ in the hypothesis, versus the particular $k$ and $t$ introduced—the canonical epimorphism and the zero map. If you are writing for beginning students, then you might consider using $g$ and $h$. If you trust your readers a little more, then go ahead and overload $k$ and $t$ if you want.) In any case, yes, the answer has a mistake in switching from $g,h$ to $k,t$.

The second potential issue you raise is: how do we know that $g \neq h$? We **cannot** deduce $g \neq h$ from the fact that they are defined differently. After all, $y=2x+4$ and $y=2(x+2)$ (from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$) are defined differently, but give the same function. A basic way to show functions are different is to show there is an element in the domain at which the functions take different values. In the quoted answer, $g \neq h$ because that they have different images. The image of $g=k$ is $C$ and the image of $h=t$ is $0$; since $\operatorname{Im} f \neq B$, we have $C \neq 0$. So the images of $g$ and $h$ are different, so $g \neq h$. This is not completely spelled out in the quoted answer.